# use of internal package xxx not allowed after rename the project

Tags: go, package, go-packages

I am trying to start my first Go project based on someone else's code, so I download his GitHub repo as zip, upload it to my own repo. Then use `go get -u github.com/@username/@repo` to install my repo, and add a replace statement to `go.mod`:

```
replace someone/repo v4.19.1+incompatible => ./
```

As a result, when I try `go test ./...` and `go build ./...` in the top directory, I get an error saying `use of internal package xxx/yyy/internal not allowed`. I am sure the only file include `import xxx/yyy/internal` is at the dir `xxx/yyy`, which should match the restriction of internal package of Go.

I don't know why `go test ./...` runs well in the original repo, but fails in my repo. Is there anything else I need to do to modify other people's repo?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Seeing how this is a v4 package, I'm guessing something is importing via the incorrect module path.

Comment: Where should I edit the module path? Sorry I am totally new to Go :/

Comment: if nothing is importing the /v4 path, then are you certain you're using module mode? What version of Go are you using?

Comment: I am not sure,  and I am using go 1.14.

Comment: I found that I changed the first line of  `go.mod` to `module myusername@repo`, change it back solves the problem... Thanks for the keywords you provided, searching them gives me some solutions. @JimB